# Action Sheet is not working in ipad ios 13.6

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, alert, uialertcontroller

My app uses UIAlertController for both ActionSheet and Alert. It works fine on iOS 13.4 in iPad, but if I run the code from my iOS 13.6 device, this is not working properly in iPad 12.9 ios 13.6.

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Select Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: 
    UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
       alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, 
    handler: { (res) in
        self.btnClickedCamera(tag:2)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, 
    handler: { (res) in
        self.btnClickedGallery(tag:2)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (res) in
        
    }))
    if let popoverPresentationController = alert.popoverPresentationController {
        popoverPresentationController.sourceView = sender
        popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = sender.bounds
    }
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: " popoverPresentationController.sourceView = sender" In this line, What is "sender"? Is "sender" is UIButton

Comment: @Ashutosh kumar Mishra sir, Yes its UIButton

Comment: Hey Pawan, I have run your code in the simulator(Device:- iPhone 11 Pro 13.6), It works properly.

Comment: @Ashutosh kumar Mishra sir, its nor working on Ipad 12.9 (4th generation) ios 13.6

Comment: Hi Pawan, Now I have used your code on iPad pro (12.9- 4th generation). Again It works properly.

Comment: Ashutosh kumar Mishra sir, apple send me error using this code. Error :- "We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 13.6 on Wi-Fi. Specifically, we found that your app did not produce any action when we selected Change profile photo or selected Add attachment in the section “Ask expert”

Button Take photo was unresponsive.

Please see attached screenshots for details."

Comment: Please check camera and gallery action on iPad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I have tried your code on iPhone(Device:- iPhone 11 Pro 13.6) and iPad(iPad pro (12.9- 4th generation) both and it works. But If you said, I have changed some popover frame, Use the following code:-*

```
   let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Select Image", message: nil, preferredStyle:
    UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
       alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default,
    handler: { (res) in
        self.btnClickedCamera(tag:2)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default,
    handler: { (res) in
       self.btnClickedGallery(tag:2)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (res) in

    }))
    if let popoverPresentationController = alert.popoverPresentationController {

        popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = sender.frame
        popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view

    }
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Select Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: 
    UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
       alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, 
    handler: { (res) in
        self.btnClickedCamera(tag:2)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, 
    handler: { (res) in
        self.btnClickedGallery(tag:2)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (res) in
        
    }))
  if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
               if let popup = alert.popoverPresentationController {
                   popup.sourceView = self.view
                   popup.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 4, width: 0, height: 0)
               }
           }
    }
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Please also briefly explain what the code is doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
 func showAlert(vc: UIViewController) {
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Select Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { (res) in
         //TODO: your action
      }))
      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { (res) in
         //TODO: your action
      }))
      if let popoverController = alert.popoverPresentationController {
          popoverController.sourceView = vc.view
          popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: vc.view.bounds.midX, y: vc.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
          popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = []
      }
      let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
          alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      }
      vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```